# java intstream parallel loop omitting data

Tags: java, parallel-processing, java-stream

I have this piece of code:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Double> results = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>();
IntStream.range(0, 100).parallel().forEach(x ->{
    for (int y = 0; y <100;y++){
        for (int z = 0; z <100;z++){
            for (int q = 0; q <100;q++){
                results.add(someMethodThatReturnsArrayListDouble);
            }
        }
    }
});

System.out.println(results.size());
```

After running this code, i get always different `results.size()`, always a few short. Any idea why is that and how to fix it?

Comment: `ArrayList` is not threadsafe.

Comment: You should read the section on side effects in [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#Statelessness)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use 
[Vector](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html)

it's a thread-safe implementation of List.

Answer (score 1):

`ArrayList` is not threadsafe. If you try and add items to it in different threads (which is what a parallellised stream does), it is likely to break.

From the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html):

> Note that this implementation is not synchronized. If multiple threads access an ArrayList instance concurrently, and at least one of the threads modifies the list structurally, it must be synchronized externally. (A structural modification is any operation that adds or deletes one or more elements, or explicitly resizes the backing array; merely setting the value of an element is not a structural modification.) This is typically accomplished by synchronizing on some object that naturally encapsulates the list. If no such object exists, the list should be "wrapped" using the Collections.synchronizedList method.

The easiest fix, in this case, would be to remove the call to `parallel()`.

Answer (score 1):

You result is not synchronized. There are multiple ways to solve your problem, the best would be letting the java stream api handle the combining of the lists.

```
List<List<Double>> results = IntStream.range(0, 100).parallel().flatmap(x ->{
        List<Double>> results = new ArrayList<Double>();
        for (int y = 0; y <100;y++){
            for (int z = 0; z <100;z++){
                for (int q = 0; q <100;q++){

                    results.add(someMethodThatReturnsArrayListDouble);

                }
            }
        }
        return results.stream();
   }).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This collects the lists in the method, and returns them as a stream to be combined at the end of the method using collectors.toList(), what is thread safe.

Comment: thanks, i will definitely try this. Before i go study doc and stuff, could you please rewrite the code if i wanted to change x with y? that the loop for x would be classic for, and the Y loop would be IntStream, i am confused where to put collector then